# MahApps.Metro Message and Progress connect

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro

I would like to create a logic with MahApps which looks like this:

```
ShowScreenCommand = new Command(async () =>
{
    var window = Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow;
    if (await window.ShowMessageAsync("Are you sure to remove it?", "Removal", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative) == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
    {
        await removePatientTask();
    }
});

private async Task removeTask()
{
    var window = Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow;
    var controller = await window.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait...","Process message",false,new MetroDialogSettings());

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    await controller.CloseAsync();
}
```

Problem is, that there is a gap between Message and Progress dialogs. One dialog hides, second one shows. This is not looking perfectly.

Is there a way to remove this gap? I mean, to replace one dialog with another?

Comment: Why do the messages change language?

Comment: ups :) I forgot to change that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the closing animation of the `ShowMessageAsync` method:

```
await window.ShowMessageAsync("Are you sure to remove it?", 
                              "Removal",
                              MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative,
                              new MetroDialogSettings 
                              { 
                                AnimateHide = false 
                              });
```

Maybe you'll have to remove the showing animation of the Progress as well, it's basically the same code, but replacing `AnimateHide` by `AnimateShow`.

Comment: After that, to go further, you can implement a `CustomDialog` and make the two dialogs in "one".